# Microsoft Botframework: Concurrent testing fails

Tags: botframework

We are working on a chatbot using MS Botframework v4. The bot is returning the data perfectly fine from QnA database when only one user is using the bot at a time. But the bot is getting confused, it seems, when multiple users are using it.

So I am having 3 categories and under each category I have 2 sub categories.
1.a,1.b
2.c,2.d
3.a,3.f

Now if there are 2 users who are using the bot at the same time but one is selecting 1.a and the other is selecting 2.c then the bot is giving garbage response.

Any inputs will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for the dialog(s) where QnA is being used? And, what is the actual query a user can submit that would produce the responses? For instance, normally someone might say "What is the company's customer support number?" with a response of "Our customer support number is ...". But, you haven't listed what might be asked and the responses, if those are the real responses, are not very diverse.